# Changing rehype-remark defaults (eg. emphasis using _ instead of *)

Tags: javascript, markdown, remarkjs

The [rehype-remark](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-remark) plugin uses [Github Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis) to parse HTML into Markdown.

In other words, it uses `*` for italic and `**` for bold.

However, I want to use `_` for italic, and keep `**` for bold. Because using only `*` is causing errors in my parser, while `_` works well.

Is there a plugin or config that changes the markdown default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the [rehyphe-remark](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-remark) plugin doesn't generate the markdown, it transforms the HTML AST (hast) to a markdown AST (mdast).

The actual markdown is generated by the [remark-stringify](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-stringify) plugin which by default uses [CommonMark](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-stringify#syntax) (not GFM).

> Markdown is serialized according to CommonMark

You can use the [options](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-stringify#unifieduseremarkstringify-options) to change the syntax of the markdown. For example, to use underscore for emphasized text (italic) instead of star you can set the [`emphasis`](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main/packages/remark-stringify#optionsemphasis) property to `_`.

Here's their usage example.

```js
import {unified} from 'unified'
import rehypeParse from 'rehype-parse'
import rehypeRemark from 'rehype-remark'
import remarkStringify from 'remark-stringify'

main()

async function main() {
  const file = await unified()
    .use(rehypeParse)
    .use(rehypeRemark)
    .use(remarkStringify, {
      bullet: '*',
      fence: '~',
      fences: true,
      incrementListMarker: false
    })
    .process('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')

  console.log(String(file))
}
```